Web Part Disappears on Edit and Apply SharePoint SE
I am working in SharePoint Server Subscription Edition. In one site collection, I create a new site page and check it out. I add a content editor web part within a 2-column layout. When I edit the web part and click OK, it disappears from view on the page. When I visit the site URL with "?contents=1", I can see the web part, but it doesn't present itself in the browser for users to view. I am struggling to allow an end user to modify data on the page since every time it is edited, it destroys itself. Any tips are welcome. Thanks!
